# How do I transfer data from javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to transfer the varible "content" to php and then a mysql database, but everything I have tryied fails. The data is comming from a iframe and the code looks like this

```
function getContentFromIframe(Textfield)
         {
           var myIFrame = document.getElementById("Textfield");
           var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;          
          if (content != "")
          {
             alert('bla, bla, bla ' + content);            

              content = 'The inside of my frame has now been saved';
              myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = content;
          } 
          else{
           alert('bla bla bla ');
         }
   }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can pass javascript variable like this

```
      if (content != "")
      {
       var url = "your phpfile ?content="+content;
        $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "post",
        success:function(response)
        {
            document.getElementById("your field").innerHTML = response;
        }
       });  
      }
```

Comment: been woorking on this one..not to lucky yet. but its late and I'm tired. Thanks for your time

Comment: It is connecting to the php program, but it dosent get the the content. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Sending data from the browser to the web server is not such a simple task. I would suggest you read up on [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Basically AJAX will allow you to send asynchronous request to the server from you JS code. The data you want sent is added as POST body or as query parameters in the URL you request, depending on the size of the data.

Also using AJAX without some extra library (Prototype/JQuery/etc) is not very easy, due to cross-browser issues. Check those out too.

Answer (score 0):

Save javascript data in hidden field and get hidden field in php code

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a request that interfaces with your server in some way. You can use a form submission, or put the variable in the query string of a URL and navigate to it (using window.location). Or an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

I needed recently to set some $_SESSION vars from onSelect on a select menu. So basically, transferring Javascript value to PHP.

It's totally doable through AJAX, and I use the simple object inited in Javascript (no JQuery or other new fancy tools for cool programmers :))

You can actually do an AJAX request, via POST or GET (read docs on AJAX), and then in the .php file on which you do the request, init a $_SESSION var (with start_session() on) which you can then access in your PHP current page.

Basically, to shed some more light, when you trigger a Javascript event, that event triggers a POST / GET request on an external .php file which can save into a database or assign a $_SESSION var, but this is all done asynchronously, and quick, so the current PHP variables are still in effect :)

cheers

Answer (score -1):

You can use Jquery to invoke a post request to a php page using AJAX and process it.